# Constrained delegation (Kerberos) only working using localhost

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2, iis-6, windows-authentication, kerberos

We have developed a WebAPI application that runs on IIS 6.2. That API uses Integrated authentication. So, the operations will be executed in the user context of the user that is calling the API.

Apart from that, because some of that operations execute remote actions to another server in the platform. We used constrained delegation (kerberos) to manage the Kerberos double hop and be validated in the remote server as the user calling the API.

We made the configuration changes in the IIS (regarding enabling Windows authentication) and we enabled "Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)" in the AD for the server running the IIS.

The current status is, if we access the API using localhost, everything is working as expected. However, if we access using the FQDN or even 127.0.0.1, it fails with unauthorized when the API call executing the remote operation behind the scenes returns.

Does anyone know what we can fix such configuration issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you did everything right...except didn't or haven't set the SPN properly in AD for the principal (computer/server object) referring to the web service running on the target server.   For example, the server name is server1, and the AD and DNS domain name is acme.com.  Then the SPN for the server in AD would need to be HTTP/server1.acme.com.   Ref:  [Setting up Kerberos Authentication for a Website in IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/)

Comment: Hi T-Heron

Sorry for the late response. I have been working in another topics and today I went back to this topic.
It is not working at all and the SPN is correctly configured in the remote servers where the users must be authenticated.

As additional information, we are executing Powershell commands (Remote Desktop cmdlets) and we enabled the delegation for 
the wsman process which I think that is the one that manages Powersheel commands.

Do you know what is missing?

Thanks

Comment: What is the SPN you are actually using, can we take a look at that?  IP addresses are not valid SPNs by the way which is why 127.0.0.1 won't work...